# Angular Checkbox Not responding

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically in the typescript file, I have a function which pushes the data into an array

So I passed in input type="checkbox" to one of the values but apparently the checkbox isn't working as it cannot be clicked or ticked

I have tried toggling the checkbox but to no avail.

```
// Array to store data
public col: Array<any> = [
    { title : 'Select', name: 'select'},
....
...
];


//Function to push
this.data.push({
"select": '<input type = "checkbox" slotId = "'+bk.slotID+'"/>',
........
........


//in html 
<div class = "row">

       <ng-table #listTble [config]="config" #ngTable="ng-table" [rows]="data" [columns]="columns">
```

The check box is displayed, but cannot be ticked,
Also on a side note i am fresh on angular but tasked to work on this angular project so I am kind of lost any insights will be valuable!

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please explain what you want to do. what I understand, you have a table. now do you want to show your checkbox values in your table? if it is possible create a stackblitz to make it clear

Comment: So the table is created in typescript and In the same ts file i am pushing the values into the table.

So the element Select has a value of <input type = "checkbox"... pushed inside the table and is displayed in html

but the displayed html checkbox doesn't have a tick when clicked.

Comment: so, I summarize your requirement. You have a table. You want to dynamically add checkbox in each row of the table that can be checked, right?

Comment: one more question, is it angular 8 or angular js code?

Comment: angular 8, i will try to add the things in stackblitz if i can because i am working on some sensitive stuff and i cannot really share code.

and yes you are right with the requirements! 
Just right now i realised that the checkbox cannot be clicked upon probably because if i push in a checkbox as a value in ts and when i display it in HTML the value becomes fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was manually pushing in a fixed Checkbox, thus it will not be able to be checked.

Also, found out that the data was displayed using a ng-table template called from ngtable.component. Thus I edited the code there to include a checkbox and its solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamically-add-checkbox) using formarray.

You can add createNew() function to your checkbox in your form. you have to wrap it within a table in own way.